# Is RTK Query ExtraOptions not strongly typed?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm trying to have it be required to provide a string (a permission name in this case) when defining RTK Query endpoints. The problem is that even though a `baseQuery` does take a generic parameter for `ExtraOptions`, and it's possible to have it be required when you make your own baseQuery, the `createApi` and `injectEndpoints` functions expect a `baseQuery` that [extends BaseQueryFn](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/d3bb412e064ad6db4fa8a83f54ba20476556f665/packages/toolkit/src/query/createApi.ts#L203), of notice is that no generic parameters are provided, which means the defaults are used, which for `DefinitionExtraOptions` is `{}` (=any non-nullish value), meaning it will allow almost any value, and not provide intellisense.

My question is: Is there a way to work around this? If it requires extra code in base query that's okay, the biggest issue is that it should be hard to make a mistake when defining endpoints, which is now very easy because `ExtraOptions` will accept any type.

Here is a minimal example: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-microservice-5vdqt8?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.ts

```js
import "./style.css";
import {
  BaseQueryFn,
  fetchBaseQuery,
  createApi
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/react";
import { QueryReturnValue } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/baseQueryTypes";

type ExtraOptions =
  | {
      requiredPermission: string;
    }
  | {}; // Removing this shoukd fix the typo issue below, but that's not allowed by createApi, injectEndpoints and the endpointBuilder

export function baseQuery(
  baseURL: string
): BaseQueryFn<string, unknown, unknown, ExtraOptions, {}> {
  // some global setup here
  return async (
    args,
    api,
    extraOptions
  ): Promise<QueryReturnValue<unknown, unknown, {}>> => {
    // pretend we check permission:
    if ("requiredPermission" in extraOptions) {
      console.log(extraOptions.requiredPermission);
    } else {
      throw new Error(
        "Invalid endpoint definition, 'extraOptions.requiredPermission' must be provided."
      ); // I think it's a big limitation that this has to be a runtime throw, not a compile time error.
    }

    return fetchBaseQuery({})(args, api, {});
  };
}

createApi({
  baseQuery: baseQuery("/"),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    correctEndpoint: builder.query<string, void>({
      query: () => "a",
      extraOptions: {
        requiredPermission: "somePerm"
      }
    }),
    badEndpointWithTypo: builder.query<string, void>({
      query: () => "b",
      extraOptions: {
        requiredPermision: "somePerm" // TYPO here, but because we have to have ExtraOptions in a union with {}, there's no error
      }
    })
  })
});
```

In an ideal case ExtraOptions wouldn't have to be in a union with {}, but that doesn't work with createApi. I have tried the alpha versions for RTK 2.0, but it's the same there. I don't feel like what I'm doing should be that uncommon, is there another way that what I need (a required, typed parameter for every endpoint) is expected to be done that I missed?

Comment: I think it's just not that a lot of people are using it, so nobody ever noticed - maybe open an issue or even a PR to fix this?